# Статистика google

Tags: php, статистика, google-search

В разделе статистики  гуголя (а также у хостера) страницы

```
http://host.dot/page.php?pararm1=1
```

и

```
http://host.dot/page.php
```

будут считаться как одна или две.

То есть статистика посещений будет для 1 и 2 адреса отдельная или общая?

По поводу хостеров: у каждого свои заморочки. А у поисковых систем как?

Answer (score 1):

Для GA вы можете гибко управлять собираемыми данными. Например, передавать руками нужные вам параметры для отслеживания названия, расположения и др.:

Например, вы можете сгенерировать нужную вам ссылку для GA с необходимой логикой:

```
var pageUrl = '/my/super/page';
ga('send', 'pageview', pageUrl);
```

По умолчанию значения GET-параметров учитываются в подсчете.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#overview

**Update**
Процессом индексирования get-параметров (в поиске) так же можно в какой-то степени управлять: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080548?hl=ru

Comment: ответ понятет - "ДА, для каждого адреса будет считать отдельно". НО  объяснение не очень. Почитаю по ссылке. Потом,отпишусь тутачки.

Comment: Ответ следует интерпретировать следующим образом: вы сами настраиваете, как будет выглядеть статистика вашего сайта в GA.